# Find string inside string using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

So I'm trying to find a efficient way of extract a string inside a string, I believe regular expressions would probably be the best approach for this, however I'm not familiar with regular expressions nor with C# & How I would go about constructing that.

I'm currently using a for loop that searches the string for a sequence, then extracts the next 3 entries after that sequence, however it isn't accurate due to entries varying in size etc.

-Example of String

```
 heythereiamexample: 12instackoverflow
```

String can vary though in terms of chars between target string

-Example of target string

```
example: 12
```

Now I don't necessarily mind on what I extract, whether it be the digits relative to the string, or the string entirely ( digits included ), but one factor is that the string must end with [0-9]+

So expected output would obviously be,

```
example: 12
```

Comment: Given your description `1` would also be a valid output. or even `2`. Please be more specific when describing your problem.

Comment: @phuzi I'm trying to extract ` example: 12 ` from ` heythereiamexample; 12instackoverflow `

Comment: What if the example was `heythereiamexample: instack12overflow`? What would be the expected output?

Comment: @phuzi Nothing because ` example: ` does not contain numeric entries

Comment: There are many good online tutorials & good online sites & offline tools for testing regular expressions - you should try those & if still having problems come back with examples of what you have tried - rather than just expect the answer to be given to you - otherwise you will remain unfamiliar with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for a key that ends with `example` followed by a value that starts with a number separated by `: ` (a colon and a space)?

Comment: "_Nothing because ` example: ` does not contain numeric entries_" Well, that's not what you explained in your question. Rather to the contrary, your question states "_Now I don't necessarily mind on what I extract, whether it be the digits relative to the string, or the string entirely ( digits included ), but one factor is that the string must end with [0-9]+_". According to this eplanation in your question, `example: instack12` could be a valid result you are looking for. If it isn't, then you should **edit** your question and correct any misleading statements. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may  get some idea from this:

```
Pattern :  example:\s*\d+

    Match groups:
    1.  example: 12
```

https://rubular.com/r/myxvmRb20ukfEP

```
            string strtext = @"heythereiamexample: 12instackoverflow";
            Regex rex= new Regex(@"example:\s*\d+");

            Match match= rex.Match(strtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
string text = "blabla12";
string regex = @"\D*(\d+)$";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, regex);
if(match.Success)
{
 string matched = match.Groups[1].Value;
 Console.WriteLine(matched);
}
```